# Migrate fields with content from drupal 6 from different DB

Tags: 7, migrations

Can't understand how migrate node fields from different DB (I mean migration to clear drupal 7 site). At first, I migrate fields by content migrate module but in this case db contain too much garbage. Tried to it by migrate module but didn't find how to do this.
Then I used migrate_d2d module, but it doesn't help at all.

Is there way to migrate fields and content without writing by hand each field migration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "writing by hand" you mean writing PHP code, then the answer is no. The [migration module](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate) is a migration framework; it provides the tools (API, PHP classes, etc) to migrate data but it doesn't do it for you. [Migrate D2D](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_d2d) (built off the Migration framework) *provides some support* with "out of the box" importing (e.g. User Roles, Pics, Taxonomy, etc.), but it doesn't do it all for you.

The key thing to understand is complexity of the problem; content in Drupal can be configured in a myriad of different ways. As such, one module that can handle all the different permutations of sources (e.g. CSV, WordPress site, various DB's, & an old Drupal install), field configurations (e.g. ints, floats, text, custom objects, custom fields, module create fields), & destinations (e.g. custom node types, module-create node types, custom entities, etc.) is a mammoth task for an open-source project.

Instead, the Migration & Migrate D2D maintainers have made the problem more tractable. They've provided some common tools that are likely to be used in *any Drupal migration*. Filling in the last bit of details (e.g. should a phone field be mapped to an address field or as a text field) is up to you because only you can possible know that information and how it's used.

Comment: So could you please help me to understand how to cook migrate d2d? Does it only make query and that all it make? How to save fields value?

Comment: The full details are too big for a DA comment, but here's a blog post ( [part 1](https://www.acquia.com/blog/drupal-drupal-data-migration-part-1-basics) & [part 2](https://www.acquia.com/blog/drupal-drupal-data-migration-part-2-architecture) ) that's a good starting point. Essentially, it involves creating a module with classes that extend the ones create in migrate_d2d. Your extended class will implement methods to build your data source, modify any data as you need, and define a constructor to map your fields.

Comment: Yeah, I saw these posts but they not tell anything about fields migration. Actually I didn't find any post where described how to use Field handlers. Agree that the answer on my question is too big.

Comment: You can checkout the [field handlers section](https://www.drupal.org/node/1429096) of the Migration documentation. Googling should yield some more resource too. If you need further help, try posting a new question that's solely focused on field handlers.